# How to make a IDE recognize JavaScript "class" referenced in other file

Tags: javascript, ide, code-completion

I'm starting to develop with JS because I want to learn WebGL. For years I've been using strong typed classes like Java, C++ and C#. But now I'm having heavly issues with JS because it doesnt have classes and variables arent typed...

So i'm trying to use a IDE to help me with some code complete and such. But I'm unable to create a "class" and make it been recognized as it on several IDEs. Tryied NetBeans, Cloud9 and Eclipse: All have the same issue.

Just to referente, this is the class (Matrix4f.js) that i'm trying to use:

```
if (typeof(exports) === 'undefined') {
    global = typeof(window) !== 'undefined' ? window : this;
}
else {
    global = exports;
}

function Matrix4f(array){
    var mat4f = new Float32Array(array);

    mat4f.translationMatrix = function(x, y, z){
        return new Float32Array([
            1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            x,   y,   z,   1.0
        ]);
};

} 


Matrix4f.create = function(){
    return new Matrix4f([
            1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
        ]);
};

Matrix4f.translationMatrix = function(x, y, z){
    return new Float32Array([
            1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            x,   y,   z,   1.0
        ]);
};

Matrix4f.scalingMatrix = function(x, y, z){
    return new Float32Array([
            x,   0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, y,   0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, z,   0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
        ]);
}; 

global.Matrix4f = Matrix4f;
```

So event making the import on a Index.html and trying to use the bellow code on other JS file the IDE says that "Matrix4f" is a undeclared variable

```
var mat4 = Matrix4f.create();
var mat4_2 = new Matrix4f([0.0]);
```

So I'm doing anything wrong, or this is a limitation of IDEs with JS? Also there is any IDE that doesnt have this problem?

I'm not asking for "the best" I just want to use some code complete...just it! And If I try to use it on browser, it works fine, so there is no syntax error on code (I think).

Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: i bet those anon wrappers are hiding your code... Also, VS2012 has the best JS hinting/parsing i've seen so far...

Comment: As an aside, why use nested IIFEs like that?

Comment: @dandavis Tried to remove the nested wrapers but didnt solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use classes and strongly typed members you can try TypeScript. It is a really nice super-set of javascript and gives you all the good stuff you are used to in Java and C#.

http://www.typescriptlang.org/

There are some plugins for some text editors and IDEs, and Visual Studio 2012 supports it very nicely.

Comment: But this TypeScript is recommended for WebGL applications? I mean when developing WebGL games we need performance and good memory management, and using this TypeScript I can reach this like in JavaScript?

Comment: It compiles down to plain javascript. It adds lots of nice things like classes, inheritance, static typing, easy module support, generics, etc. But it all compiles down to javascript, and none of that extra overhead makes it across. Personally, I think it would work great for game development.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2012 supports this kind of code completion out of the box. The answer by davesters81 mentions it as a good choice for TypeScript, but even without TypeScript you get *good* JavaScript intellisense support in VS (one of the best on the market).

Evidence (I copy-pasted the Matrix-code into site.js):

[image]